# Handle selecting all in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm building a simple folder management system using React and Redux. One of the requirements is the ability to select multiple files using shift.

e.g. if I have the following structure with Folder B selected:

```
[Folder] Folder A
[Folder] Folder B *
[Folder] Folder C
[Folder] Folder D
[Folder] Folder E
[File] File 1
[File] File 2
[File] File 3
[File] File 4
[File] File 5
```

Now if the user holds down the shift key and clicks on File 3 I want everything between (and including) Folder B and File 3 to be marked as selected.

My store looks something like:

```
    {
      directoryData: {
        directories: [{id: 1, name: 'Folder A'}, {id: 2, name: 'Folder B'}, ...],
        selected: [2]
      },
      fileData: {
        files: [{id: 1, name: 'File A'}, {id: 2, name: 'File B'}, ...],
        selected: [1, 2]
      },
    }
```

I'm at a loss as how to handle this situation. If all the items were stored in a single array, I could've handled it quite easily in a reducer, however since both the `directoryData` and `fileData` subtrees are affected, that doesn't seem to be an option.

What I almost need is a top-level component of some sort that has access to both the state of the files and directories, calculates which items should be selected and then, for example, calls `directoryActions.select()` or `fileActions.select()` for each item that needs to be selected.

I've avoiding putting anywhere near this much business logic in a component thus far, and was wondering if there were a better approach to tackle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a different state structure:

```
{
  directoryData: {
    // array of mixed directories and folder with visual ordering
    content: [{ type: 'directories', id: 1 }, { type: 'directories', id: 2 }, { type: 'files', id: 1 }, { type: 'files', id: 2 }],

    // optional: array of selected mixed directories and folder
    selected: [{ type: 'directories', id: 2 }, { type: 'files', id: 1 }],

    directories: { the directories data
      1: {id: 1, name: 'Folder A'}, 
      2: {id: 2, name: 'Folder B'},
    },
    files: { // the files data
      1: {id: 1, name: 'File A'}, 
      2: {id: 2, name: 'File B'}
    }
}
```

- To select using shift, you just copy a slice by indexes from the
  `content` array to the `selected` array. The other option is to added a `selected` proptery to the items in content, and toggle it. I prefer the `selected` array, because it's easiter to manipulate the selected items.
- If you add a file or directory, you add them in their respective
  collections, and then add a reference in the `content` array.
- To remove you do the opposite of add.
- To change a file or directory, you replace the object in the
  respective collections.